# Trigger new python script when class name is met and then return when script is done

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, triggers

I am trying to figure out to have my first script go to a second script but only when the first script
experiences a new web page with specific text on it at some point.

I am using selenium and webdriver.

file 1 (file where trigger event happens)

```
from creroute import test

   if True:
        #try:
            content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('message')
            #driver.find_element_by_class_name("message")
            test()
```

file 2  (new script to run)

```
def test():       
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
```

Comment: So... where is your problem? Please read how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use the os module.

```
import os

os.system('python second_script.py')
```